# Drawing a grid using squares in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm pretty new to programming and I've just started studying algorithms, I wanted to create an algorithm that draws a grid as a challenge instead of using the GridLayout() method. For some reason my squares only start drawing a little below the beginning of the top of the window and the side of the window, and I did not find the reason why this happens.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFrameSquares extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int rows = width/30;
        int cols = height/30;

        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawRect(i* rows,j* cols,i* rows,j* cols);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(380,380);

        JFrameSquares panel = new JFrameSquares();
        window.add(panel);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Screenshot, please. `g.drawRect(i* rows,j* cols,i* rows,j* cols);` - same params for x,y and width,height. May be `g.drawRect(i* rows,j* cols,rows, cols);`?

Comment: That Solved the problem, thank you very much :)